# Search results are not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am new in iOS developing. In my project I have taken a tableView and a search bar. Now when I am searching one of the datas of my tableview, no search results are coming. Can anyone please solve my problem?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is my ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *postData;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *arrDetail;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *searchResults;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *parserTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *mySpinner;


@end
```

This is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_mySpinner.hidden = NO;


[self fetchData];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}


- (void) fetchData {

 [_mySpinner startAnimating];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=Message&this=isNotReal"];
_postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://svn.indusnettechnologies.com/HHC/webservice/users/countrylist?apiKey=hgfyhfyi87hgc67"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:_postData];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    _postData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else{
    //error
}

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
// so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
// Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
// also serves to clear it
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[_postData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
// self.data parse

NSDictionary *dict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.postData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
self.arrDetail = [dict valueForKey:@"Countries"];

[self.mySpinner stopAnimating];
self.mySpinner.hidden = YES;

[self.parserTable reloadData];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var

}

#pragma mark Table View Delegates


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];

UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
lbl1.text = [[self.arrDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];

UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl2.text = [[self.arrDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"CountryName"];

UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
lbl3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", indexPath.row];


return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

//return [self.arrDetail count];

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [_searchResults count];

} else {
    return [_arrDetail count];

}

}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

_searchResults = [_arrDetail filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];


return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` there is no mention of `_searchResult`. So even if your `filterContentForSearchText:scope:` works you won't update it according to your filtered data.

Comment: Then what should I do? @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following method like I have done:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSMutableDictionary * tempDict;

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
{
    tempDict = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else 
{
    tempDict = [_arrDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
lbl1.text = [tempDict valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];

UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
lbl2.text = [tempDict valueForKey:@"CountryName"];

UILabel *lbl3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
lbl3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", indexPath.row];


return cell;

}
```

Problem is also in your predicate. change it

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    //country_name and country_code are keys in your dictionary of country
    NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country_name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country_code contains[cd] %@", searchText];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[p1, p2]];

    _searchResults = [_arrDetail filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

Comment: No results are coming! Should I change anything in numberOfRowsInSection? @Gadhiya

Comment: Place breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check the value of tempDict

Comment: I got an issue. When I am placing breakpoint in filterContentForSearchText, in _searchResults array nothing is coming. @Gadhiya

Comment: Set break point in `filterContentForSearchText` method and check what is happning

Comment: Could you post any one object of _arrDetail?

Comment: I told you in previous comment that what is happening in filterContentForSearchText and in _arrDetail there are country name and country code. In country name 229 countries are there and the search text can be anything country name or code anything. @Gadhiya

Comment: problem is with your predicate in `filterContentForSearchText `. see the edit

Comment: Dude got it! I am getting objects in _searchResults. But just a little problem is occurring. The app is crashing. The crash log is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'. Please once look into this.

Comment: Have you changed `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ad per my answer? I have edited this also.

Comment: I have changed everything according to your answer. Now the crash is gone, objects are coming in _searchResults, the number of cells are coming but the datas are not showing in the table after searching. @Gadhiya

Comment: When I am placing breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and checking the value after searching something, in every variables values are coming instead of the labels. @Gadhiya

Comment: Have you changed `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as i have edited in my answer